# how to install fuzzystrmatch.sql pg_trgm.sql on postgresql on mac os x

Tags: mac, postgresql

I have installed postgresql according to [this](http://www.studiotips.net/docs/tips_sql/postgresql/installingpostgresqlonmac.html), but I also need fuzzy string match functions, but I have no idea how to install these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Mac, the .sql files are in a folder such as
/Library/PostgreSQL/8.3/share/postgresql/contrib

Comment: For me, it was in /Library/PostgresPlus/8.3/share/contrib .

Answer (score 30):

If you are looking for levenshtein or other functions in fuzzystrmatch package in postgresql **9.1**, just do this:

```
# Login with postgres user and:
psql my_database -U postgres
# Enter the postgres password and type in the psql shell:
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

Done.

Answer (score 8):

If you can't find that extension, it's possible you didn't install postgres contrib.

for instance, on centos style os's:

```
yum install postgresql93-contrib
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752456/how-to-enable-contrib-modules-on-heroku-postgres-database) in the context of a Rails migration, all it takes is:

```
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
create extension pg_trgm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually with a sql file full of functions, it is something like this:

```
cat fuzzystrmatch.sql | psql {database name}
```

Comment: the problem is, where can I get that file?, it isn't in my system.

Comment: Ask the guys from "PostgreSQL for Mac".